# Sitecore powershell console not displaying state field

Tags: powershell, sitecore, sitecore7, sitecore7.2

I've a sitecore template with field name state. Where a state field has a  drop link field which displays the country states from "Country State" node.

I'm trying to write a query which shows all the courses with given states.

But when I run the query below it shows "**Sitecore.Data.Items.ItemState**".

```
gci -recurse | format-table state
```

Any idea on why it's not displaying the state GUID value instead?

Comment: We need more inforation to help you.  Is this is a site on the web?  Currently, I have no idea what you're trying to do.  Please give examples.

Comment: Good chance says that `state` does not have a good `ToString()` method. What happens if you just do `gci -recurse | select state`?

Comment: What about changing the field name. I think Sitecore is globally using the name "State". Try updating the name like "Country State" instead of "State" and try the code again. `gci -recurse | format-table "Country State"`

Answer (score 4):

I understand this is long overdue and you have probably dealt with it long time ago, but for the sake of anyone who would run into it in the future, let me explain why and how.

The reason why `State` returns the `Sitecore.Data.Items.ItemState` text is that the Sitecore items contains a property named `State` on the `Item` object.

Sitecore PowerShell Extensions attaches additional dynamic properties on to the object that expose your item fields. Those however cannot collide with the existing item properties which would be the case here. To avoid the collision SPE will detect it and prepend the dynamic property with an underscore. In your case the one liner that would give you the expected results would be:

```
gci -recurse | format-table _state
```

or if you wanted to display the property as `State` still rather than `_state` you could use the following syntax:

```
gci master:\content  | format-table @{Name="State"; Expression={$_._state } }
```

Hope this still helps someone.